# Junit console output to log

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

I want to know,

How can I get **Junit** console output to log file?

As example, I have put `Assert.equals()` methods. I want to know passed method and what are the failed methods also.  I tried to find method to do that, but I was unable.

Comment: Can you just use shell redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the **Log4j** Java library. It can be configured to output formatted messages to console and external files.
Here are some tutorials:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j
- http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example

In the second one see the code with lines:

```
...
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log4j-application.log
...
```

This is where you put the path to the output text file.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using eclipse, you can achieve it by going to Run configuration > Common > Output file> giving path of your log file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:

```
    private void log(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.flush(); // the magic is here
    }
```

PS: It works for Ant launched from pure console without any IDE. You may have to add more magic like Thread.sleep(1000) for IDEA IDE.